# Ionic 2 - Link tab page dynamically using root

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

In ionic 2 i can able to create tabs dynamically using JSON response by the following code. i need to link the created tabs dynamically with their corresponding pages dynamically using [root] in

```
    <ion-tab *ngFor="let rew of people" [tabTitle]="rew.name"></ion-tab>
```

tabs.ts

```
export class TabsPage {

public people: any;
public result: String;
public pep: any;
public tabs : any;

 tab1Root = HomePage;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public peopleSearch: PeopleSearch) {
 this.loadPeople();   
 }

 loadPeople() {

this.peopleSearch.load()
    .then(data1 => { 
      this.people = data1.children[0].children

      var result =JSON.stringify(this.people);
                console.log("Tabs : ",result);

     }
    );
  }
}
```

JSON Response

```
  Tabs :  [{"category_id":5,"parent_id":2,"name":"Masala Mix","is_active":1,"position":1,"level":2,"children":[]},{"category_id":3,"parent_id":2,"name":"Pure spices","is_active":1,"position":2,"level":2,"children":[]},{"category_id":6,"parent_id":2,"name":"Pickles","is_active":1,"position":3,"level":2,"children":[]},{"category_id":8,"parent_id":2,"name":"Rice Mix","is_active":1,"position":4,"level":2,"children":[]},{"category_id":4,"parent_id":2,"name":"Asafoetida","is_active":1,"position":5,"level":2,"children":[]},{"category_id":9,"parent_id":2,"name":"Pappad","is_active":1,"position":6,"level":2,"children":[]},{"category_id":11,"parent_id":2,"name":"Become A Stockist ","is_active":1,"position":7,"level":2,"children":[]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting index to the pages and select tabs using 'selectedIndex' in ion-tabs,

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex={{index}}>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="PageOne"></ion-tab> // 0 activates this page
   <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="PageTwo"></ion-tab> // 1 activates this page
   <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="PageThree"></ion-tab> // 2 activates this page
</ion-tabs>
```

Hope that helps